# Error in weblogic.xml : cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'prefer-application-packages'

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, xml-parsing

I am using springs source tool suite.
I am getting an error in weblogic.xml file--

```
cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'prefer-   
application-packages'. One of '{"http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/weblogic-web-app":retain-
original-url, "http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/weblogic-web-app":show-archived-real-path-
enabled, "http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/weblogic-web-app":require-admin-traffic,    
"http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/weblogic-web-app":access-logging-disabled}' is expected.
enter code here
```

and my weblogic.xml looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<weblogic-web-app xmlns="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/weblogic-web-app"     
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/weblogic-web-app   
http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.0/weblogic-web-app.xsd">
<jsp-descriptor>
    <keepgenerated>true</keepgenerated>
    <page-check-seconds>60</page-check-seconds>
    <precompile>true</precompile>
    <precompile-continue>true</precompile-continue>
</jsp-descriptor>
<container-descriptor>
    <optimistic-serialization>true</optimistic-serialization>
    <prefer-application-packages>
        <package-name>antlr.*</package-name>
        <package-name>javax.persistence.*</package-name>
        <package-name>org.apache.commons.*</package-name>  
    </prefer-application-packages>
    <show-archived-real-path-enabled>true</show-archived-real-path-enabled>
</container-descriptor>

</weblogic-web-app>
```

the error is shown at the beginning of  tag..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
weblogic-web-app
xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_0.xsd
http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app
http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.4/weblogic-web-app.xsd">
```

changed the namespace to the above one.. it worked now..

Answer (score 5):

I don't know anything about weblogic, but the schema you reference at

http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.0/weblogic-web-app.xsd

shows what child elements are expected inside a container-descriptor element, and they don't permit a prefer-application-packages element.

Answer (score 0):

Order should be same as given below

```
<wls:timeout-secs>1800</wls:timeout-secs>
<wls:cookie-path>/my</wls:cookie-path>
<wls:cookie-secure>true</wls:cookie-secure>
<wls:cookie-http-only>true</wls:cookie-http-only>
<wls:url-rewriting-enabled>false</wls:url-rewriting-enabled>
```