# Configure weblogic.xml to send secure JSESSIONID

Tags: java, xml, weblogic, jsessionid

I'm trying to add to weblogic.xml file `<cookie-secure>` tag:

```
<wls:session-descriptor>
    <wls:timeout-secs>1800</wls:timeout-secs>
    <wls:cookie-path>/my-web</wls:cookie-path>
    <wls:cookie-http-only>false</wls:cookie-http-only>
    <wls:url-rewriting-enabled>false</wls:url-rewriting-enabled>
    <wls:sharing-enabled>true</wls:sharing-enabled>
    <wls:invalidate-on-relogin>true</wls:invalidate-on-relogin>
    <wls:cookie-secure>true</wls:cookie-secure>
</wls:session-descriptor>
```

But an error appears:

```
cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with element 'wls:cookie-secure'. No child element is expected at this point
```

How is possible to solve the problem?

Comment: Have you looked tried changing the order? Also have you looked at similar errors like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14556050/error-in-weblogic-xml-cvc-complex-type-2-4-a-invalid-content-was-found-starti http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12893675/invalid-deployment-descriptors-in-deployment-descriptor-file-web-inf-web-xml-in

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Indeed the problem was in order

Comment: Glad I could help. You are allowed to "accept" your own answer if you want to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right order is:

```
<wls:timeout-secs>1800</wls:timeout-secs>
<wls:cookie-path>/my</wls:cookie-path>
<wls:cookie-secure>true</wls:cookie-secure>
<wls:cookie-http-only>true</wls:cookie-http-only>
<wls:url-rewriting-enabled>false</wls:url-rewriting-enabled>
```