# Spring weblogic error

Tags: java, spring

I got source code from my client.

Spring with tomcat. I use Eclipse STS IDE for spring.

and got error in weblogic :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wls:weblogic-web-app
    xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.0/weblogic-web-app.xsd">
    <wls:weblogic-version>12.1.3</wls:weblogic-version>
    <wls:context-root>api.elastic</wls:context-root>
    <wls:container-descriptor>
         <wls:prefer-application-packages>
             <wls:package-name>com.fasterxml.jackson</wls:package-name>
         </wls:prefer-application-packages>
     </wls:container-descriptor>
</wls:weblogic-web-app>
```

invalid content was found with element : `wls:prefer-application-packages`

and when I tried to force run it with tomcat server :

```
Jul 23, 2018 3:53:11 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:api.elastic' did not find a matching property.
Jul 23, 2018 3:53:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.0.53
Jul 23, 2018 3:53:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Jun 29 2018 14:42:45 UTC
Jul 23, 2018 3:53:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number:         8.0.53.0
Jul 23, 2018 3:53:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Mac OS X
Jul 23, 2018 3:53:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            10.13.6
Jul 23, 2018 3:53:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          x86_64
Jul 23, 2018 3:53:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Jul 23, 2018 3:53:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.8.0_144-b01
Jul 23, 2018 3:53:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
Jul 23, 2018 3:53:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         /Users/emerio-ridho/Documents/workspace-sts/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0
Jul 23, 2018 3:53:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         /Users/emerio-ridho/Downloads/apache-tomcat-8.0.53
Jul 23, 2018 3:53:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/Users/emerio-ridho/Documents/workspace-sts/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0
Jul 23, 2018 3:53:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/Users/emerio-ridho/Downloads/apache-tomcat-8.0.53
Jul 23, 2018 3:53:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=/Users/emerio-ridho/Documents/workspace-sts/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps
Jul 23, 2018 3:53:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/Users/emerio-ridho/Downloads/apache-tomcat-8.0.53/endorsed
Jul 23, 2018 3:53:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
Jul 23, 2018 3:53:11 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /Users/emerio-ridho/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.
Jul 23, 2018 3:53:11 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Jul 23, 2018 3:53:11 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Jul 23, 2018 3:53:11 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Jul 23, 2018 3:53:11 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Jul 23, 2018 3:53:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 563 ms
Jul 23, 2018 3:53:11 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Jul 23, 2018 3:53:11 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.53
Jul 23, 2018 3:53:14 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Jul 23, 2018 3:53:18 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Jul 23, 2018 3:53:18 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Jul 23, 2018 3:53:18 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Jul 23, 2018 3:53:18 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 6577 ms
```

I've tried google any clue, but I dont solve it untill now.

Comment: Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\eclipse\workspace\api.elastic2\src\persistent.properties (No such file or directory) have you checked for that file?

Comment: sorry I copy wrong log, that case has been solved before

Answer (score 0):

Can the following namespace be used as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14556050/error-in-weblogic-xml-cvc-complex-type-2-4-a-invalid-content-was-found-starti)?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wls:weblogic-web-app
    xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_0.xsd
        http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app
        http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.4/weblogic-web-app.xsd">
    <wls:weblogic-version>12.1.3</wls:weblogic-version>
    <wls:context-root>api.elastic</wls:context-root>
    <wls:container-descriptor>
         <wls:prefer-application-packages>
             <wls:package-name>com.fasterxml.jackson</wls:package-name>
         </wls:prefer-application-packages>
     </wls:container-descriptor>
</wls:weblogic-web-app>
```

Comment: error on weblogic xml solved, thanks dude, buat the tomcat, still error